# Click toggle function disabling preventdefault

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm trying to execute a script that toggles between two functions when touchMenuButton is clicked. When it's clicked I want to add and remove a class, and when it's clicked again reverse it and remove and add those classes. But it's not working and I can't figure out why.

```
$(function () {
    var touchMenuButton = $("#touchmenubutton");
    var touchMenuCanvas = $("#touchmenucanvas");
    var touchMenuDrawer = $("#touchmenudrawer");

    $(touchMenuButton).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(touchMenuButton).on("click", function () {
        if $(touchMenuCanvas).hasClass("canvas-closed") {
            $(this).removeClass("canvas-closed");
            $(this).addClass("canvas-open");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("canvas-open");
            $(this).addClass("canvas-closed");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(touchMenuButton)` --> `$("#touchmenubutton")`. I don't understand why are you not just getting values directly. You are calling `$(...)` inside a `$(...)`, which is more complicated then it needs to be.

Comment: SO went down for maintenance as I was putting together an update of my answer, but one of your problems was that you don't have parentheses around your if method: `if (...) {...}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do all that if'ing. Just toggle the classes:

```
touchMenuButton.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    touchMenuCanvas.toggleClass("canvas-closed canvas-open");
});
```

That said, your code should work. I can't say more without more information or a demo.